# Iptables DROP SSL traffic (443)

Tags: ssl, https, iptables

I'm trying to block any request to a SSL GET resource with specific parameters using iptables, i.e.: https://domain.com/hello?param=aux

I have already blocked traffic to port 80 with the following command (we assume that iptables rules list is empty):

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --string "GET /hello?param=aux" --to 70 --algo bm -j DROP
```

It's very straightforward to think that the SSL version is (at least for a non-expert like me):

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m string --string "GET /hello?param=aux" --to 70 --algo bm -j DROP
```

However it is not working. Any ideas of what I am doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It will never work, since all traffic to SSL site is encrypted, including the request method and parameters.

Comment: I understand @Nickolay Olshevsky , any advice to do this?

Comment: No good way to do this. That's the purpose of SSL - to hide content from eavesdroppers.